# Como incrementar e decrementar usando FOR?

Tags: javascript, lógica, for

Eu não estou conseguindo incrementar a variável a cada clique em um *button*.

Exemplo: um **Button** e um **Parágrafo**, a cada clique no *button*, aumentar o valor no **Parágrafo**, de exemplo, do 0 para 1, e cada clique ir incrementando um.

```js
function criaCounter(init) {
    var count = init || 0;
    return function() {
        count++;
        alert(count);
    }
}

$('#addCount').click(criaCounter(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente é questão de escopo.

Basta tirar a declaração da variável do corpo da função, veja o código funcionando logo abaixo, clicando em "executar":

```js
var count = 0; // tiramos esta linha da função

function criaCounter(init) {
    count = init || count;
    return function() {
        count++;
        alert(count);
    }
}

$('#addCount').click(criaCounter(5));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addCount">Clique aqui</button>
```

Note que o `for` mencionado na sua pergunta não guarda relação com o que você pediu para que aconteça. Você não quer um *loop*, e sim uma ação única a cada clique.

Note que troquei o `count = init || 0;` por `count = init || count;` simplesmente para não zerarmos o valor nas chamadas seguintes.